# C++ Template - In-class Struct

Tags: c++, templates

For the following code, I got a compilation error at implementation line as:
"B does not define a type". 
I am aware of solution of put the function definition inside of class declaration. Is it possible, though, to have the function definition out of the template class declaration? Thanks

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    public:
        // ctor, dtor and interface funcs etc

   private:
     struct B {
          T value;
          B *next;
     }

     B *locate(const T& val) const;

     // blah blah
};

template<typename T>
B *A<T>::locate(const T& val) const
{
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `B` is defined inside `A` you should qualify it with `A<T>::`:

```
template<typename T>
typename A<T>::B *A<T>::locate(const T& val) const
{
    //logic
}
```

Also note `typename` which is required because `B` is a dependent name.

Comment: Thanks, you are spot on. The "typename" is what I was missing.

Comment: Confirmed Feng Deng is correct; and this has helped me to understand templates even more when nesting other classes or structures within a class template.